# Display Popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have drop down with "Create New" option.
    I need to  display the popup window when user clicks "Create New" in dropdown then Popup should display.

```
 function ShowPopup()
 {

    var a = document.getElementById('<%= DropDownConfigFile.ClientID %>').selectedIndex;          
    var b = document.getElementById('<%= DropDownConfigFile.ClientID %>').options[a].value;         

    // window.ShowPopup("ModalPop.aspx");
    window.open("ModalPop.aspx", "List");
```

I am calling this function here like,

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownConfigFile" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker" onchange = "ShowPopup()">
```

but popup is displaying in another window. not on the same window.
    any wrong in this code.

Comment: Your code opens a new window like a popup, not a modal popup. Refer to bootstrap popups instead. Or in jquery.

Comment: Hi I have tried with this. But not coming still.

Comment: Have you tried referring w3schools ? Here is an example they provide [sample code](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal2&stacked=h). Also you can check this page for more help [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for

[Jquery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

and also refer

[Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Popup Using Bootstrap</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```